# Set HTML img attribute to Angular binding

Tags: html, angular

Inside the HTML class for my Angular component, I have an image displaying with:

```
<div class="row" id="work">
  <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="">
      <img class="img-fluid" width="100%" [height]="height" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
      <img class="img-fluid" width="100%" height="100" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
      <img class="img-fluid" width="100%" height="100" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

In my typescript file for the component, I have a height variable being set to "100" on init.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  height = "500";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.height = "500";
  }
}
```

On page load, the image height is equal to the default images height, it it not reading/using my height variable. Probably something silly, but not sure what.

EDIT:

"img-fluid" was the problem. It ignores the height attribute, sets height to auto, so I couldnt set it myself from Typescript.

Comment: jus use  square brackets `[src]="url"` for example `[height]="height"`

Comment: `[height]="height"`

Comment: @penleychan doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Oblivion try this then `[attr.height]="height"`

Comment: @JoelJoseph doesnt work, think maybe my Typescript might be the issue?

Comment: @Oblivion, It is working here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y9f1ci as per your code, What is your issue then??

Comment: @ManirajfromKarur edited my question.

Comment: You should inspect your element and play around with the css, I suspect that there's a conflict with bootstrap class you are using.

Comment: @penleychan you were correct. The fluid image was ignoring the height attribute. Its auto when fluid. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "img-fluid" tag was the problem. It ignores the height attribute, sets height to auto, so I couldnt set it myself with Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<img class="img-fluid" width="100%" height="{{height}}" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Hi, neither your answer or [height]="height" have any affect.

Comment: No not working, and no errors, cleared Cache just in case and no effect.

Comment: Did you try @Sachin Gupta's answer?

Comment: I did, no effect

Comment: can you try like this 
`<img class="img-fluid" width="100%" [style]="{height: height}" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="">`

Answer (score 0):

@penleychan is correct, just wrap height in braces and reference the height variable as its value. But to clarify why yours isn't working as is, you're just missing surrounding quotation marks:

`height="{{height}}"`

If I'm not mistaken, adding quotes would make yours work as well. But @penleychan's method is much more common.

Comment: Do you have any external styles coming into play? You could try doing ```[ngStyle]="{'height': height}"```

Comment: Also no effect. Is my typescript the issue? (in the edit)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
[ngStyle]='{height:height}'
```

### edit

Or use like this: here 'x' is the condition (if any) and "200px" is the default height. 
     `[ngStyle]='{height : x ? "200px" :height}'`

Comment: Hi, no effect. Thinking my Typescript is the issue?

Comment: you have to set height in 'px','vh'.. or whatever css takes